# How to know Back Button exist on Windows Devices - Hardware/Software - Windows 10 Desktop/Mobile App - C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, back, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I need to check whether a particular Windows device that runs my application have the back button, either on the device's hardware or in software (Windows 10 in tablet mode).

Someone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to know if there is a hardware / system provided one, or do you want to **force** the system to draw one for you? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

For the hardware back button, you can easily check it using ApiInformation.IsTypePresent method.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        bool isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent =
            Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons");

        if(isHardwareButtonsAPIPresent)
        {
            // add Windows Mobile extenstions for UWP
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
    }

    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        // hareware button pressed
    }
```

Comment: Right. Thanks.
But for virtual back button, type run Windows 10 in Tablet mode, any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn439322.aspx) the back button should be always present for: Phone, Tablet, Surface Hub.

As for Desktop/Laptop software button in the title bar of the app can be enabled/disabled. You can check if it's visible by getting a property [AppViewBackButtonVisibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager.appviewbackbuttonvisibility):

```
bool isSoftwareButton = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility == AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
```